# Control iPad with other iOS device

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am working on an app for the iPad and would like to be able to include the option to use a separate iOS device to control it. I have seen examples of this with games (notably [Chopper 2](http://gizmodo.com/5526387/chopper-2-uses-your-iphone-as-a-fancy-ipad-controller)), but have no idea how it is done.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the iOS frameworks that back this feature? I have looked through the SDK but cannot find the relevant sections.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure they use [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html) or you could use the lower level [Bonjour discovery](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40002520).

Read through the GameKit docs.

You can start there. I guess the controller is actually a separate feature of the app that just sends messages over the network, using sockets to send and receive the data.

Send over the network from the controller. Receive them on the ipad in a running thread or however the service you use handles it. process the received messages.

Comment: As the app isn't a game, I will look into using Bonjour. Thanks a lot alJaree.

Comment: GameKit is [not just for games](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008303-CH1-SW1): "Although designed with games in mind, this network is useful for any type of data exchange among users of your application."

Comment: @Jack - As Daniel said, you can use the services GameKit provides. It might be easier to use than Bonjour depending on your experience with networking.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @alJaree. I'm working on something similar, though I've found it much easier to implement through Unity. Prime31 has a number of sweet plugins that allow you to implement things like Bluetooth through gamekit in a single line of code. I'm on my ipad right now so I cant be sure of the exact URL, but I think it's just prime31.com, in their 'unity' section.

Comment: Paid services um...... Depending on what the OP has in mind, shortcuts could be good or bad. @Jack. If you want to actually learn and develop your programming skills and knowledge of the API, you know the way to go ;)